# How to convert a string in yyyy-mm-dd format to a Javascript Date Object without considering the date as UTC

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I really just have a simple question. I want to convert a string in yyyy-mm-dd to a date object in javascript. This seems simple enough. You can just do the following.

```js
var date = new Date('2020-04-08');
```

But in this case, javascript considers the date '2020-04-08' as UTC midnight. So the actual date that is returned to me is the following.

```
Tue Apr 07 2020 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

I know I can create a date in the following format

```
var date = new Date(2020, 3, 8);
Wed Apr 08 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

But it looks like too much hassle to extract the year, month and date from the already nicely formatted date string. Isn't there a simple way to convert yyyy-mm-dd string to a date object without it being treated as UTC date?

So in the simplest terms, my question is how do I tell the date constructor that the date I am passing is not a UTC date but a local date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply append `'T00:00:00'` to your date string.

```js
const dateString = '2020-04-08'
const timeString = 'T00:00:00'

const date = new Date(dateString + timeString);
console.info(date.toString())
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

> Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I actually read this exact line before posting the question but I guess it didn't occur to me that just appending 'T00:00:00' will actually make the Date constructor treat the date as local. I think the documentation should be updated to something like the following. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local. If you don't want the '1970-01-01' to be treated as UTC then just append 'T00:00:00' to your date string.

Comment: Fails in Safari, which treats it as UTC regardless. The built–in parser should be avoided if at all possible, strings should be manually parsed with a function or library. If a library is used, the format should always be supplied. Also see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: Ah, curse you Safari! I always though ISO 8601 was safe with the `Date` constructor